# Angular 9 tslint no output rename

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, angular9

I'm using the @Output decorator in an angular 9 project and the code this this:

```
@Output('myMethod') myMethod: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Typescript gives my an error and forces me to add this about the code in order to remove the error:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-output-rename
```

How can I fix this without having to disable the rule?

Comment: Do your really need the 'myMethod' passed to @Output, this is already the name of the field so not necessary.  The tslint rule is meant to enforce naming the field as you want the property to be seen in templates rather than renaming via the decorator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a tslint warning.
To fix it you should not rename the output.

Try to do something like this:

```
 @Output() myMethod: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Answer (score 1):

- find the [rule description](http://codelyzer.com/rules/no-output-rename/) by keyword 'no-output-rename'
- it references [Angular ccoding style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-13%20with%20a%20solution) which contains description with a solution

```
@Output() myMethod: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```